# Streaming audio/video file from url in android

Tags: android, streaming

I want to stream audio(mp3)/video(mp4) file from url and also want to set seekbar so user can seek the song to time . IF user seek the song than it should start playing from that. I am able to stream and play a file from url but can't add seekbar to implement see functionality. any example or any help.

thanks in advance

Comment: ithink this is help full to you :: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/media/MediaPlayerDemo_Video.html

Answer (score 3):

i have created a demo project, i think it will be helpful to u

**Here's the activity class**

```
public class VideoViewDemoProj extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoViewDemo";

    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private EditText mPath;
    private ImageButton mPlay;
    private ImageButton mPause;
    private ImageButton mReset;
    private ImageButton mStop;
    private String current;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
    //  mPath.setText("http://logisticinfotech.com/extra/Veer.mp4");
    //  mPath.setText("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rkOySwlEtVk&amp;feature=youtube_gdata_player");
        mPath.setText("http://logisticinfotech.com/client/full-volume.mp4");
        mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
        mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
        mReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);

        mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playVideo();
            }
        });
        mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.pause();
                }
            }
        });
        mReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.seekTo(0);
                }
            }
        });
        mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (mVideoView != null) {
                    current = null;
                    mVideoView.stopPlayback();
                }
            }
        });
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                playVideo();

            }

        });
    }

    private void playVideo() {
        try {
            final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
            System.out.println("path --> "+path);
            Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
            if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
                Toast.makeText(VideoViewDemoProj.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
                if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.start();
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                current = path;
                System.out.println("Current path --> "+path);
                mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();

                System.out.println("end try in play");

            } 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    }

    private String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException {
        if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
            return path;
        } else {
            URL url = new URL(path);
            URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
            cn.connect();
            InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
            if (stream == null)
                throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
            File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "mp4");
            System.out.println("hi");
            temp.deleteOnExit();
            String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();

            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
            byte buf[] = new byte[128];
            do {
                int numread = stream.read(buf);
                if (numread <= 0)
                    break;
                out.write(buf, 0, numread);
            } while (true);
            try {
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            }
            return tempPath;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**XML file is as under**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
    <EditText android:id="@+id/path"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/surface_view"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            >
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/play"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/play"/>

        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/pause"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/pause"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/reset"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/reset"/>
        <ImageButton android:id="@+id/stop"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/stop"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

**Add the below permissions in AndroidManifest.xml file**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```